# Non-negative array subtraction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938086/non-negative-set-subtraction) is so close to what i am looking for but not quite there. What I am looking is I have an array of integers, and a value that I need to subtract from across said array.  i want to zero out each index before moving on to the next. I don't want any numbers less than 0 nor do i want any decimals.. so, for subtractFromSet([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 25) instead of returning:

```
[0,0,0.666666666666667,1.666666666666666,2.666666666666666]
```

I want:

```
[0,0,0,0,5]
```

Comment: Please re-write your question so it will be standalone one. Not one that depends on other Q.

Comment: Any special rules how to transform your input to the desired output? Because if you have an input `([a1, a2, ..., an], b)` your desired result seems to be `[0, 0, ... 0, sum(a1, .. an) -b)]` ie all elements of the array are `0` except the last, which is the difference between the sum of the array and `b`

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop until there is nothing left to subtract.

```js
function subtractFromArr(arr, val){
  const res = [...arr];//copy
  for(let i = 0; i < res.length && val > 0; i++){
    const take = Math.min(res[i], val);
    res[i] -= take;
    val -= take;
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(subtractFromArr([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 25));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array "number" of times, while subtracting 1 from the current index and moving to the next index when index is equal to 0

```
function subtractFromSet(array, number) {
  var i = 0;
  do {
    array[i]--;
    number--;
    if(array[i] == 0) i++;
  } while (number != 0);
  return array;
}
subtractFromSet([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 25);
```